# How to substitute environment variable in command of service in docker-compose.yml at runtime of container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

The following `docker-compose.yml` defines `command`, which contains an environment variable `FOO`

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      FOO: foo
    command: ["echo", "${FOO:-foobar}"]
```

If you run

```
docker-compose -p app up
```

and look at the logs of the container using

```
docker logs app_tmp_1
```

you see

```
foobar
```

since the environment variable `FOO` is substituted, when/before `docker-compose.yml` is parsed/read. If the environment variable `FOO` would be substituted at runtime of the container `app_tmp_1`, the output would be

```
foo
```

as the environment variable `FOO=foo` is configured for the container.

How to configure `command` to substitute/evaluate the environment variable at runtime of container `app_tmp_1` (i.e. output `foo` in the example)?

Comment: You can put it in the `.env` file.

Comment: This does not use the environment variable of/in the container. It just uses the value of `.env` instead of the default specified in `docker-compose.yml`. The time at which the substitution is done, is the same (when `docker-compose.yml` is parsed).

Comment: Why would you want the things written in `docker-compose.yml` to be evaluated at container run-time? Even if you make that work somehow, it would be very confusing. Try working with the structure/system instead of bending it to your will.

Comment: Either way is confusing ;) It depends on your assumptions/background. For example, `command` in Docker Compose is handled differently than `CMD` in Dockerfile (see [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)). `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]` substitutes at container runtime, but `command: [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]` does not.

Comment: Besides, it is good to know, how the substitution actually works or what doesn't. For example, the nested substitution does not work probably in Docker Compose  (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68937127/1065654)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can escape the environment variable (double dollar symbol `$$` instead of one `$`) in `docker-compose.yml` to prevent it from being replaced in the command of the container. However, since the replacement should be done at runtime, a shell (command) has to be run in the container to do the replacement, e.g.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      FOO: foo
    command: sh -c 'echo "$${FOO:-foobar}"'
```

**Old answer:**

I just figured out that nested environment variables are not replaced.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      FOO: foo
    command: sh -c 'echo FOO is "${FOO_OVERWRITE:-${FOO:-foobar}}" && env'
```

If you run

```
docker-compose -p app up
```

you get

```sh
# echo output
FOO is foo
# env output
FOO=foo
```

You get the same result, even if you run

```sh
FOO=ignored docker-compose -p app up
```

However, if you run

```sh
FOO_OVERWRITE=overwritten docker-compose -p app up
```

you get

```sh
# echo output
FOO is overwritten}
# env output
FOO=foo
```

The overwrite does not work probably, since `}` is part of the output. Considering this, you should not use this solution ;)

> **Note:** You do not get `}` if you run the same command in a shell (no Docker involved):
>
> ```
> $ sh -c 'echo FOO is "${FOO_OVERWRITE:-${FOO:-foobar}}"' 
> FOO is foobar
> ```

If the environment variable is not defined in the container, i.e. remove

```yaml
    environment:
      FOO: foo
```

from `docker-compose.yml`, i.e.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    command: sh -c 'echo FOO is "${FOO_OVERWRITE:-${FOO:-foobar}}" && env'
```

you get the default defined in the command

```sh
# echo output
FOO is foobar
# env output does not contain FOO
```

---

Docker Compose version 1.26.0

Comment: The perfect answer, @maiermic you should accept your own answer as solution

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the environment variables in the docker-compose are not available at the time of creating the container with the docker-compose.

The same problem you have is when putting environment variables in docker-compose and expect them to be available during building-phase with Dockerfile (in the build-stage of docker-compose).
Then they are also not available.

What you could do is the following:

### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  tmp:
    image: alpine
    container_name: fooContainer
    volumes:
      - ./start.sh:/root/start.sh:ro
    environment:
      FOO: foo
    command: ["/root/start.sh"]
```

### start.sh

And since start.sh script runs inside the container you will have environment variable available.
start.sh looks something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo $FOO
```

### result

```sh
$ docker-compose up
Creating fooContainer ... done
Attaching to fooContainer
fooContainer | foo
fooContainer exited with code 0
```

Comment: It is a workound that works (in most cases), but it requires to define another file on the host, which might not work (e.g. if you change `DOCKER_HOST` to run on a remote host, where the file is not present).

Comment: You are right, it's a workaround. And one without having read the docs, sorry :-)  See here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: To which part of the documentation do you refer to? Have I overlooked a solution (no workaround) to my described issue?

Comment: Right at the top: "Substitute environment variables in Compose files".

Comment: I haven't found a solution (no workaround) to my described issue in that section. Should I?